# getElementByID return null (because not loaded yet)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, load, getelementbyid

Good day everybody,

I'm trying to get an element by its ID in javascript and it returns me `null`.

Actually this element isn't fully load when the DOM is because of the plugin Restrict Content Pro (where the targeted element is from) making request after page is loaded *(see the ref. image below)*.

The temporary solution I wrote is basically a 2 sec `setTimeOut` on the `getElementByID` function which is kind of ... brutal. ☺

If the plugin takes more than 2 sec to load, it won't work.

So, my question is : do you know any way to properly do so?

Something like

`- while returns null
    try to get it
- when returns element
    stop the loop`

> *good to know* : `document.onload` or `window.onlaod` won't work since the plugin loads element after the page is fully display.

Thanks in advance!

[image: When the page is loaded, the plugin is still displaying elements (Restrict Content Pro plugin with Stripe)]

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Does it works like "When something changes in the DOM, do function"?

Comment: I don't know, I can't read

Comment: Surely there's a callback on the plugin you are using, that you can use to fire a function when the plugin done it's thing?

Comment: (don't think I'm actually sat down waiting for a solution, I'm reading the doc about MutationObserver right now. I just didn't heard about it before and already tried many many things)

Comment: Restrict Content Pro doesn't provide callback functions ?

Comment: Can you post fiddle of your code?

Comment: Well I didn't found callback function on the RCP doc, I'm calling the form through shortcode within Wordpress admin. Simply `[register_form]`

Comment: quick search on RCP doc, for email tag it provide a callback function
http://docs.restrictcontentpro.com/article/1761-adding-a-new-email-template-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

```
do {
   var getId = getElementByID();
   if(getID!=null){
    // to do 

   }
}
while (getId==null);
```